# XSLT Convert each repetitive elements into unique records

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to create a unique record for each repetitive elements for Project and Skill. Tried with my known options in XSLT and I am not getting a right result.

Could you please help me in generating XSLT for the below input XML.

Input XML:

```
<root>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
 <Skill>java</Skill>
<Project>def</Project>
<Skill>unix</Skill>
<Project>efg</Project>
<Skill>xml</Skill>
<Project>pqr</Project>
<Skill>sql</Skill>
<Project>xyz</Project>
<Skill>Analytics</Skill>
</Record>
</root>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
 <root>
 <Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>abc</Project>
<Skill>java</Skill>
</Record>
 <Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>def</Project>
<Skill>unix</Skill>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>efg</Project>
<Skill>xml</Skill>
</Record>
 <Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>pqr</Project>
<Skill>sql</Skill>
</Record>
<Record>
<Emp_ID>288237</Emp_ID>
<Emp_Name>John</Emp_Name>
<Country>US</Country>
<Manager>Wills</Manager>
<Join_Date>5/12/2014</Join_Date>
<Experience>9 years</Experience>
<Project>xyz</Project>
<Skill>Analytics</Skill>
</Record>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done simply by:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="root/Record/Project">
            <Record>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../*[not(self::Project or self::Skill)]"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::Skill[1]"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"  />
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="Record/Project">
            <Record>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Emp_ID"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Emp_Name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Country"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Join_Date"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../Experience"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="following::Skill[1]"/>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```